# How use @Input like a Signal in angular 16?

Tags: angular

I want to use signals with @Input but not works.

I builded a table component with some @Inputs, but i want to use it with signals.

Something like:

```
export class TableComponent {
    @Input() headers = signal<any[]>([]);
    @Input() keys = signal<any>([]);
    @Input() data = signal<any[]>([]);
}
```

How i set the signal value with the value pass into input? Have another approach to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signals can be used like any other input. The code you posted is not really wrong, but there must be a mistake somewhere else in the code. And the reason can be that you initialize your signal inputs in TableComponent. If you want to use them like any other input, you would initialize (create) the signals outside of the TableComponent and insert them.

See stackblitz example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kfkauw?file=test%2Ftest.component.ts

**The following code is a full working solution bases on Angular v16.2:**

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, signal } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  parentSignal = signal('Value set in App Component');
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<div>
   <app-test [childSignal]="parentSignal"></app-test>
</div>
```

**test.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, Input, Signal } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],
})
export class TestComponent {
  @Input() childSignal?: Signal<string>;
}
```

**test.component.html:**

```
<div *ngIf="childSignal">{{ childSignal() }}</div>
```

**Remarks:**

- If want to keep the signals inside of the child component (TableComponent in your case) and you only want to update the value of the signals by the input binding, you can achieve that by using private signals inside of the component and by using getters and setters to update the values/retrieve the values.
- You should not use 'any'. By using any, you loos the benefits, TypeScript offers.

Comment: Thank you for answer.

About your remark of use any type, considering the table component used to display different data types, how can i set the type of my variable based on input passed?

Comment: @AugustoMentz try to narrow down the types as much as possible. You could use UnionTypes for allowing different types or you could have a common interface for all allowed inputs. If there is no other solution, you could use type "unknown". By this, you don't need to know the type of the input from the beginning. But you would be forced to check the actual type as soon as you use it.

Answer (score 4):

Signals inputs aren't supported at the moment, they are expected in a future release.

In the mean time you could play with setters.

```
export class TableComponent {
    private _headers: WritableSignal<any[]> = signal([]);

    @Input() set headers(headers: any[]) {
       this._headers.set(headers);
    }
}
```

Comment: Specifically, check out the "Signal-based inputs" section of [Sub-RFC 3: Signal-based Component](https://github.com/angular/angular/discussions/49682) for information about how they're expected to work once implemented. There are also several comments [like this one](https://github.com/angular/angular/discussions/49682#discussioncomment-5513230) that might be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Angular v17.1 released signal-based component inputs, see e.g. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#1710-2024-01-17 and https://justangular.com/blog/signal-inputs-are-here-to-change-the-game

Example:

```js
  readonly userIdSignal = input<string|null>(null);
  // or
  readonly userIdSignal = input.required<string>('some default');
```

Comment: How would you replace `@Input() set x(y: number) { this._x = y; // some other actions after } ` with signal based input?